# Can i include multiple statements when creating a one-line for loop?

Tags: python, data-science

I have an array I want to iterate through. The array consists of strings consisting of numbers and signs. 
like this: €110.5M
I want to loop over it and remove all Euro sign and also the M and return that array with the strings as ints.
How would I do this knowing that the array is a column in a table?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide code you’ve already written and input along with expected output.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about it being a one-line for loop?  I think creating a separate function to clean up values would be a Good Thing.  Also, it's not clear what you expect to be done with "€110.5M".  Is that supposed to become `110.5` (which is actually a float) or is it supposed to become `110500000`?  If all you want do is remove the the Euro symbol and the M, then use [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: it is supposed to be 11050000 yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a string comprehension:

```
numbers = [float(p.replace('€','').replace('M','')) for p in a]
```

which gives:

```
[110.5, 210.5, 310.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just `strip` the characters,

```
>>> x = '€110.5M'
>>> x.strip('€M')
'110.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sanitize_string(ss):
     ss = ss.replace('$', '').replace('€', '').lower()
     if 'm' in ss:
         res = float(ss.replace('m', '')) * 1000000
     elif 'k' in ss:
         res = float(ss.replace('k', '')) * 1000
     return int(res)
```

This can be applied to a list as follows:

```
>>> ls = [sanitize_string(x) for x in ["€3.5M", "€15.7M" , "€167M"]]
>>> ls
[3500000, 15700000, 167000000]
```

If you want to apply it to the column of a table instead:

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.price.apply(sanitize_string) # Assuming you're using DataFrames and the column is called 'price'
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, IMHO. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to construct one list from another:

```
foo = ["€13.5M", "€15M" , "€167M"]
foo_cleaned = [value.translate(None, "€M")]
```

str.translate replaces all occurrences of characters in the latter string with the first argument `None`.

Comment: Just an FYI: I find `.strip()` better for this case. :-)

Comment: But `€13.5M` should become 13500000 as indicated by OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr = ["€110.5M","€110.5M","€110.5M","€110.5M","€110.5M","€110.5M","€110.5M"]

f = [x.replace("€","").replace("M","") for x in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) on a string as often as you like. An initial solution could be something like this:

```py
my_array = ['€110.5M', '€111.5M', '€112.5M']
my_cleaned_array = []

for elem in my_array:
    my_cleaned_array.append(elem.replace('€', '').replace('M', ''))
```

At this point, you still have strings in your array. If you want to return them as ints, you can write `int(elem.replace('€', '').replace('M', ''))` instead. But be aware that you will then lose everything after the floating point, i.e. you will end up with `[110, 111, 112]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to do that.

```
import re

str =  "€110.5M"
x = re.findall("\-?\d+\.\d+", str )
print(x)
```

I didn't quite understand the second part of the question.